# URL Object is nil after creating it with let constant string url

Tags: swift

Why does the first example give me a nil and the second example give me a valid URL object.  I am trying to use this jsonUrlString constant and it's not working.

1)

```
    let jsonUrlString = """
                            https://myURI.domain.com/
                       """

    let temp = URL(string: jsonUrlString)
```

2)

```
    let temp = URL(string: "https://myURI.domain.com/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example has lots of extra spaces in the URL so it's not valid.

It's the same as:

```
let temp = URL(string: "                        https://myURI.domain.com/")
```

It would work if you had:

```
let jsonUrlString = """
https://myURI.domain.com/
"""
```

This defines the string without the extra spaces.